# what is exactly total bid quantity and total ask quantity?

Tags: trading

this is the definition formulated by me:

**Quantity total bid:** It’s the sum of currently open (remaining untraded and active) orders on the bid side.

**Quantity total ask:** It’s the sum of currently open (remaining untraded and active) orders on the ask side.

I'm a programmer so I'm not an expert in this kind of stuff.

So, could you please explain it more? 
And I will appreciate if you give me the formulas and an example to calculate them.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about the metadata of a particular exchange. Have you tried looking in the metadata dictionary for that exchange?

Comment: That's the issue, they only have this much of information,2 lines of information

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to tell us which exchange you are talking about, which markets, which instruments? It may or may not matter for this particular question, but it's good practice in general to provide the relevant context, as that will enable you to get good answers, quickly.